# Excel VBA MAC address format & extract to columns as text 00 changes to 0 or 01 changes to 1

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

and thanks in advance for advice:
I have a spreadsheet with col **G** containing MAC Addresses in format **01:00:5e:00:00:09** my code shown below takes the MAC and splits at the colon placing each of the 6 elements into the next 6 columns. **H through M.**

**Problem** is that the data is not going over as string in each case.
So as the mac above [01] becomes [0], [00] becomes [0] and [09] becomes [9].
What I am trying to achieve is that the [00] etc. stays exactly as [00] in each of its new cells.

I have tried preformatting the sheet data with a **'** so '01:00:5e:00:00:09

I have tried preformatting in the code (see below) .NumberFormat ="@".

What else might I try please?

'OPTION EXPLICIT'

```
Public Sub SplitingD()
Dim myRange1 As Range
Dim myRange2 As Range
Dim myRange3 As Range
Set myRange1 = ActiveSheet.Columns(7)   
Set myRange2 = ActiveSheet.Range("H1")
Set myRange3 = ActiveSheet.Range("H1:N" & fLastR)
myRange1.NumberFormatLocal = "@"
myRange2.NumberFormatLocal = "@"
myRange3.NumberFormatLocal = "@"
    myRange1.Select
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=myRange2, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierSingleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:=":", _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), _
        Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Grateful Stephen G6SGA

Comment: Use string format, not general one. `.NumberFormat = "@"`, not `.NumberFormatLocal = "@"`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the format in the `FieldInfo` array(the second number in each array pair) to `2`.

Text to Columns does it conversion prior to putting the values in the fields and thus the `01` becomes the number `1`, then it uses the format of the cell.

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), _
        Array(5, 2), Array(6, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

The first number is the column number and the second is the data type: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype

Comment: if `xlTextFormat` is defined (it ought to be) it probably is a better choice than `2`

Comment: @Yorik except even when using the macro recorder, excel itself uses `2` in this case instead of `xlTextFormat `